# What is the best option to list all sub-folders that a user has access to if the user does not have permission on the library or on the root folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

We have the following folder structure inside a SharePoint online site's document library to manage our customers:-

Documents

1. CustomerA

- Main
- General
- Specs

2. CustomerB

- Main
- General
- Specs

3. CustomerC

- Main
- General
- Specs

now for the "Specs" sub folders, we are granting some users (let name them junior-team) read-access. but those junior-team users do not have any permissions on the library nor on the root folder nor on the customer folders. so currently for the junior team to be able to access the "Specs" sub-folders, they will need to have the sub-folders direct URLs. since if they access the library or the site or the customer folders, they will get access denied.

so what is the best option to manage this? I found this workaround, is to use the PnP modern search web part >> then to only query the sub-folders named "Specs". so, in this case the users can access this web part and see all the "Specs" sub-folders. but not sure if there is a more straight forward or better approach to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior in the SharePoint. If users have permissions for sub folder, they can only access the sub folder through link.

As a workaround, you could use quick links web part to display all links. It makes easier for users to access Specs sub folders.